# Variadic Templated Function with Arguments all of Same Type

Tags: d, template-specialization, variadic-functions, lvalue

How do I restrict a variadic templated function to forcing its arguments to all be of the same type?

I need this for a specialization of

```
CommonType!T either(T...)(T a) if (a.length >= 1)
{
    static if (T.length == 1)
        return a[0];
    else
        return a[0] ? a[0] : either(a[1 .. $]);
}
```

that can forward l-values using `auto ref` as return type. Something along the way

```
auto ref either(T...
```

that should satisfy

```
unittest {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    either(x, y) = 3;
    assert(x == 3);
}
```

This allows values to be forwarded through the logicals `either` and `every` (not shown) similar to Lisps's `and()` and `or()`.

This would enable even more powerful use of functional constructs in D for those who prefer it.

**Update**

I believe I've found a *working* solution as:

```
/** Returns: true if all types T are the same. */
template allSame(T...) {
    static if (T.length <= 1) {
        enum bool allSame = true;
    } else {
        enum bool allSame = is(T[0] == T[1]) && allSame!(T[1..$]);
    }
}

CommonType!T either(T...)(T a) if (a.length >= 1) {
    static if (T.length == 1) {
        return a[0];
    } else {
        return a[0] ? a[0] : either(a[1 .. $]);
    }
}
auto ref either(T...)(ref T a) if (a.length >= 1 && allSame!T) {
    static if (T.length == 1) {
        return a[0];
    } else {
        return a[0] ? a[0] : either(a[1 .. $]);
    }
}

alias either or;
```

However, the body of the two versions of `either` are identical. This seems unneccessary. Is a mixin the best way to remove this redundancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to write a template that determines if all types in a type tuple are the same:

```
template allSame(T...)
{
    static if (T.length <= 1)
        enum bool allSame = true;
    else
        enum bool allSame = is(T[0] == T[1]) && allSame!(T[1..$]);
}
```

Then just use this as a template constraint:

```
CommonType!T either(T...)(T a) if (a.length >= 1 && allSame!T)
```

Comment: I was surprised as well. Phobos has quite a lot of functions on type tuples, but doesn't have that one.

Comment: My solution works for most cases. However if we want it to forward `const` and `immutable` references aswell I believe I should modify the second example somehow. But I don't know how to specify the variadic argument `ref T a` as an `inout`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

With regard to your `allSame` template, you can also use `allSatisfy` from `std.typetuple`:

```
import std.typetuple;

/** Returns: true if all types T are the same. */
template allSame(T...) {

    template isType(X) { enum bool isType = is(X == T[0]); }
    enum bool allSame = allSatisfy!(isType, T);
}

void main()
{
    static assert(!allSame!(int, float, string));
    static assert(allSame!(int, int, int));
    static assert(allSame!(int));
}
```

Comment: Also could do `(NoDuplicates!T).length == 1`, although it's not as self-documenting :)

Comment: That's nice! 3 more chars (don't get me started on SO rules..)